# C# SSH Create.Command Newline Syntax

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm definitely new to C# but learning it to pickup where another left things at work so be gentle if I ask silly questions (I think this is an easy one).  I'm using SSH.NET and the current code isn't wrong but the way the previous guy wrote it can leave open ssh connections on the other side.

Current working code opens the SSH session as normal but uses something like this to run commands on the remote system:

```
Stream.Writeline("part of the command")
Stream.Readline();
Stream.Writeline("second part of command")
Stream.Readline();
Stream.Writeline("last part of command")
Stream.Readline();
```

This works and gathers the data exactly as it should but I've seen repeated times where the SSH connection stays open afterwards on the remote system.  What I would like to do is send this all within a single command via create.command like:

```
command1 = client.CreateCommand("full command to run")
result = command1.Execute()
```

My problem is that the command I'd like to run on the remote system requires returns to run, it's a database command:

```
mysql -u user <<EOF
select COUNT(*) from table1
go
EOF
```

What I'd like to do:

```
command1 = client.CreateCommand("mysql -u user <<EOF\nselect COUNT(*) from table1\ngo\nEOF\n")
```

How/can one insert returns into the Create.Command?  I'm assuming so, see no reason why not but I'm having a hard time finding the correct syntax to send a database command that requires returns after each line like above via the Create.Command.  I've tried using \n for newlines but 99% sure I'm using it incorrectly.

And just to be clear I used mysql as the DB example, it's actually a sybase database but uses that syntax to connect.

Comment: Learn about `\n` and other escapes, or `@""` literals (verbatim strings)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use Bash heredoc syntax in a SQL command; that won't work.

Comment: Thanks guys, found that \n was working, I just wasn't getting the output I expected.  After parsing things it's working with Create.Command instead of using Stream.Writeline, works much faster and I don't see connections hanging up in the database since it works so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the breaks in the first place? They're just to nicely format the query for humans. MySQL isn't human. It couldn't care less. why not just do it this?

```
mysql -u user -e 'select count(*) from table1'
```

you don't need a `go` command, period.

If you DO want to send multiple commands, then you still don't need any line breaks, just a `;`:

```
mysql -u user -e 'command1; command2; command3; ....'
```

Comment: It's unfortunately a proprietary database that isn't mysql (sybase) otherwise I would do it that way since I have another server I connect to using PSQL and I use that syntax.  Actually just checked my logs though and think my \n is working as intended just other things causing an issue, looks like it is running the command properly on the system.

Comment: if it's sybase, then why do you have mysql up there? probably should put sybase into the question tags, then.

Comment: Sorry figured it was more of a one-off DB and folks are more familiar with mysql since it's so similar.  Think I found the problem is the output from my command, the command is working as intended to run on the system since I see it in the DB logs but think it has unexpected output that I'm feeding into the rest of the code causing issues.  Honestly needed to ping some ideas off people for this because I'm kinda solo on this project.

Comment: And just to be sure I say it, the \n does work as it should for a newline, I was expecting just the data as output but got some more than expected so I just need to parse my output to make things work.  Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**USE *\r\n* like in here:**

```
command1 = client.CreateCommand("mysql -u user <<EOF\r\nselect COUNT(*) from table1\r\ngo\r\nEOF\n")
```